# Regex to parse deployment or job name from a Kubernetes pod name

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse Kubernetes Pod names for logging.

My pod names always look like this

```
<deployment>-<replicaset>-<uid>
<job>-<uid> <-- if created by a job
```

Here are some samples

```
events-worker-7c9b7bdc55-f7sgc
notification-585f6b94b8-t4jjc
report-generator-749ccf648d-gd9j7
static-content-8445d7f556-wbxvp
init-database-fm44h <-- if created by a job
```

What I am trying to get is the *<deployment/job>* part.
For above samples this would be

```
events-worker
notification
report-generator
static-content
init-database
```

I started with something like this

```
(?<role_name>.*)(?:-[a-z0-9]{8,10})(?:-[a-z0-9]+)
```

and ended with this

```
(?:(?<role_name>[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*))-(?<=-)[a-z0-9]+-(?:(?<=-)[a-z0-9]+)
```

But I am unable to match both cases (when the name has a replicaset and if it has none)

It either does not match *init-database-fm44h* at all or only captures *init* instead of *init-database*.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(?<!-)(?<role_name>[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*?)(?:-([a-f0-9]{10}))?-([a-z0-9]+)\b(?!-)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qRiJwA/1).

*Details*:

- `\b(?<!-)` - a word boundary not immediately preceded with `-`
- `(?<role_name>[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*?)` - Group "role_name" with ID 1: one or more letters or digits and then zero or more sequences of `-` and one or more letters/digits as few times as possible
- `(?:-([a-f0-9]{10}))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching a `-` and then ten hex chars captured into Group 2
- `-` - a hyphen
- `([a-z0-9]+)` - Group 3: one or more letters or digits
- `\b(?!-)` - a word boundary not immediately followed with `-`.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I had to change {10} to {8,10} as not all replica set ids were 10 characters. But other than that it worked like charm!